# Using FileOutputStream to download multiple files

Tags: java

I'm currently writing an application that has to download certain files from the internet. I am using FileOutputStream and am able to download one file, just not sure how to do more efficiently. (Temp

```
 public static void downloadFiles() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Downloading!");
    URL website = new URL("http://example.com/");
    URL libs = new URL(website + "libs");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("index.php");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Done Downloading!");
}
```

I can get 'website' to download fine, and while I could just duplicate the process for 'libs', I feel like there's a better method.

Thanks!

Comment: You 'feel like there is a better method' why?

Comment: @EJP It's just duplicating lines and opening more streams. I want to open the smallest amount possible so there's minimal strain.

Comment: Well of course you have to open more streams, one per file, but what does 'duplicating lines' mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code.  You may ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more ways than this, but you can try putting a parameter on your method and then using the parameter to download needed files.

`public static void downloadFiles(String libFiles) throws IOException {`